# How can I determine the current state of the mouse buttons?

Tags: tkinter

I am trying to diagnose a problem with touch input in Windows 10.  Things mostly work, but I have encountered a problem the symptoms of which suggest that what I have inferred from mouse events and what should be true is not quite correct.  In order to diagnose the problem, I want to be able to ask, "Which buttons are currently down?"  (Can be only one or none with touch.)  I don't see how to do that.  Using winfo_pointerxy(), I can ask, "Where is the mouse pointer?"  I would have expected something similar for the mouse buttons; but I can't find it.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in tkinter to answer the question about which buttons are pressed. Typically what one does is attach bindings that set and unset a global variable.